# HTML div formatting: three images that dynamically match viewport size (image slider)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to writing HTML and CSS, but I am on the final step of creating my website. Namely, the image slider which resides in the background.

> The Issue: The pictures are not centered respective to the viewport.
>   The first image, for example, should have some padding on the left and
>   should be vertically aligned so as not to move when the height of the
>   image increases to match the viewport height. It should remain
>   centered behind the body of the page.

**New Issue**: When the first image's width expands over the viewport's, the images begin to move off-center because they are being locked at the left-hand side of the parent class/viewport. Is there a property that will allow the child class elements to expand past the parent's boundaries?

Could some of you wise web devs help me out here?

CodePen full version of the website: [CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/Gmanicus/full/RmKgmP)

Please go to "Full View", minimize your browser, and shorten its width to see what I mean.

Here is my HTML code for the slider:

```
<!-- Inside <html></html> and below <head></head> -->

<div class="background_carousel">
    <div class="carousel_slides">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="./img/slideshow/s%20(1).jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <img src="./img/slideshow/s%20(2).jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <img src="./img/slideshow/s%20(3).jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS for the slider...

```
.carousel_slides {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #999999;
    width: max-content;
    text-align: center;
}

    .carousel_slides .slide {
        position: static;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
    }

    .slide img{
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Huge thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use position and dynamic adjust left with click

Comment: I was able to get it working, but have a new issue that cropped up. I edited the post.